# How to cancel jobs with node-schedule from a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to node.js and programming in general. I have a function in Node that gets called from the external main file of my server which calculates some dates and sets Jobs with node-schedule.

The function runs every time a date is added. This means at the moment I have the problem that my jobs get set several times with the same value.

I'm searching for a method to cancel my Jobs from outside this function, so I can later individually cancel specific jobs from the server's main file. This is the function that updates my Jobs.

```
exports.UpdateCron = function () {
  var date1 = new Date();

  var group1 = schedule.scheduleJob(date1, function(){
    console.log('group1 start');
  });
};
```

This is the function I would like to call from my main file, but `group1` is not defined here. Can someone explain how I can access my Job `group1`, which is defined in the first function, from the second function?

```
exports.DeleteCron = function () {  
  group1.cancel();
};
```

Both function are in the same file that includes node-schedule.

Comment: Just store the `group1` in a data structure that is accessible from where you need to delete it - in your case, a variable in the module scope should suffice.

Comment: Those two functions are in the same file. Can u maybe give an example how to achive this. I´m quite new to node.js Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit old but I found it when looking for answers myself. It appears this is merely a scope issue. For future readers, this should solve OP's issue:

```
let group1;

exports.UpdateCron = () => {
  const date1 = new Date();

  group1 = schedule.scheduleJob(date1, () => {
    console.log('group1 start');
  });
};

exports.DeleteCron = function () {
  if (group1 && group1.cancel) group1.cancel();
};
```